# Collect cookies from a website using jsoup

Tags: android, html, android-studio, cookies, jsoup

I have to build an android application that takes any website and return all cookies in this website with their domain attribute.

I'm using **jsoup** for connection and parsing html, but I don't know how to collect its cookies. I'm not that much familiar with "jsoup" because this is the first time tI'm using it.

Are there any suggestions? I would be grateful.

I have tried this but do not appeal correct:

```
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(editText.getText().toString()).cookies(cookies());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Jsoup.connect("...")` you get an object implementing the `Connection` interface ([see API](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect-java.lang.String-))

The `cookies` method you are calling on the `Connection` instance is meant to **set the cookies** for the HTTP request. In order to retrieve the cookies from the HTTP response, you need to get an instance of `Connection.Response`, which you can obtain by calling [`connection.execute()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#execute--).

To sum up, your code should be something like:

```
try {
    Map<String, String> cookies = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").execute().cookies();
    System.out.println(cookies);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // error handling
}
```

As an additional consideration, keep in mind that in Android you're not allowed to perform network calls from the main thread, otherwise you'll get an Exception.